# Integral test application

Tags: sequences-and-series, improper-integrals

[image]

I'm pretty sure I haven't made any mistakes in part 1), but I have absolutely no idea how to do part 2). I don't even know what the question is asking and I've never seen anything like it before. I don't see how the sum subtracted from the sum can be anything other than 0?

Comment: to calculate approximate solution you can substitute $n$ in place of $r$ , assuming that as $n$ is large the value of summation may hold , but it's an approximate method

Comment: You might attract more respondents and proofreaders if you type up your posts. Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\frac 1{n\ln^2n}$ is a decreasing function.  From the Reimann integral:

$\sum_\limits{n=j+1}^{k} \frac 1{n\ln^2i}<\int_j^k \frac1{\ln^2n}dn <\sum_\limits{n=j}^{k-1}\frac1{n\ln^2n}$

find $k$ such that:
$\sum_\limits{n=k+1}^{\infty}\frac1{n\ln^2n}<\int_{k}^{\infty} \frac1{n\ln^2n}dn <10^{-3}$

Answer (score 0):

In the second question, it should be find an $N$ such that 
$$\left|S-\sum_2^N \frac{1}{n\ln^2 n}\right|\lt 10^{-3}.$$
The tail (sum from $N+1$ on) is less than
$$\int_N^\infty \frac{1}{x\ln^2 x}\,dx.$$
The above integral is  $\frac{1}{\ln N}$, which is $\lt 10^{-3}$ if $N\gt e^{1000}$. A big number! We can do somewhat, but not much better. The convergence of our original sum is very very slow.